# SQL Server performance is slow when migrated from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, sql-server-2014, upgrade

We are trying to migrate from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014 on Windows 2012 R2 OS.

After the upgrade, we are doing performance testing and observed huge difference in running a simple query from only one table (No joins at all).

The query is getting executed in 4 seconds in SQL Server 2012, but taking more than 1 minute in SQL Server 2014.

The SQL Servers are installed on 2 different VMs (different IP addresses). 
They have only one SQL Server instance on each machine.

The processor / ram / hard drive space is same between 2 machines.

The machines have the same applications installed. We are running the same select query from the SQL Server Management Studio directly.

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans of both queries?

Comment: Verify that the two VM's perform the same, just because they're set up with the same specs does not mean the underlying systems and/or disk systems act the same. Also make sure "power save" isn't turned on, on one of the machines or the underlying systems.

Comment: Did you follow common guidelines when migrating/upgrading SQL Server instances? See for example [Upgrading to SQL Server 2014: A Dozen Things to Check](http://thomaslarock.com/2014/06/upgrading-to-sql-server-2014-a-dozen-things-to-check).

Comment: This may be due to new CE in 2014.Please change compatibility level to 110 and see if that helps. Make sure SQL Server 2014 is patched to latest CU(I guess its CU6)

Comment: Is the max memory same on both the servers ?

Comment: How was the data migrated? Imported or restored from backup? Are the tables in question identical including indexes? Do they have any manually calculated statistics? Have you rebuilt indexes and updated stats? If you repeat your test query does it get faster or stay the same?

Comment: Even if the servers are the same how much memory has sql got to use? Server ram? Sql max memory? Is anything else happening on the server? Is cpu load and memory usage comparable before you run your test query? Are the vms on the same host? And is the host over committed? We recently had a case of poor vm performance caused by the host struggling to find resource slots. We reduced cpu from 4 to 2 and perf doubled.

Answer (score 0):

This most probably has something to do with the new cardinality estimator.

See my reply to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94354/ms-sql-server-cpu-load-goes-up-dramatically-when-turning-on-2014-features-by-set/94356#94356).

If performance improves when you change the compatibility mode you have a good chance you are running in the same problem.