# how to get database settings such as LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION and INTERLEAVED_EXECUTION_TVF

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, configuration, database-internals, compatibility-level

I am moving some database finally to compatibility level 150 using the script below

```
        USE [master]
        GO
        ALTER DATABASE [DB1] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 150
        GO
        USE [DB1]
        GO
        ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = ON;
        ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET INTERLEAVED_EXECUTION_TVF  = OFF;
        ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET DEFERRED_COMPILATION_TV = OFF;
        ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET BATCH_MODE_ON_ROWSTORE = OFF;'
```

I would like to create a rollback for this script but how can I find the current value of `LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION` and the other settings?

I know that using `OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 9481 /*force legacy CE*/)` or having a trace flag 9481 would [force that behaviour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94356/22336).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sys.database_scoped_configurations DMV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-scoped-configurations-transact-sql) exposes database-scoped configuration settings of the current database. This example query returns the currently configured values for settings in your question:

```
SELECT name, value
FROM sys.database_scoped_configurations
WHERE name IN(
         N'LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION'
        ,N'INTERLEAVED_EXECUTION_TVF'
        ,N'DEFERRED_COMPILATION_TV'
        ,N'BATCH_MODE_ON_ROWSTORE'
);
```